# How to design an iPhone app that uses both Portrait and Landscape in Flash CS6

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, screen-orientation, flash-cs6

So I have created an App that has a different menu when it is held portrait, but changes when held landscape.
I can get the navigation to work, However I am unsure how to design landscape pages inside Flash?

My stage is set to the standard 640x960 air for iOS, which gives me perfect portrait pages, But when I tilt my phone to landscape the screen obviously changes, and it looks weird. Im hoping someone can tell me how i can get this view inside Flash, while still having the portrait screens too?

I want to have both Portrait and Landscape in the same app, and am currently so confused how I can design this inside flash?

I hope this makes sense, and that someone could throw some help my way!

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy, but you can do it. First, you have to wait until stage is initialized and set it's scaling property to no scale (this will stop resizing page to fill screen). Then you have to listen to stage's resizing (it trigger's every time you rotate iPhone) and to move/scale your display objects in proper way in the listener handler.

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init); //Wait for stage initialization

private function init(e:Event):void { //init handler
   removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init); //remove listener, which won't be used more

   stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE; //set null scaling and top-left align
   stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

   stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resize); //add handler for resizing
}

private function resize(e:Event):void { //triggers every time iPhone being rotated
   //Move/scale your objects here
}
```